Are incomplete magic squares with some integral entries necessarily purely integral
A magic square is an $n \times n$ table with rational entries (including negative values and $0$) such that the sum of entries in every row, column and both diagonals is some unknown value $k$. Magic squares can be complete, when all entries are filled out, or incomplete, where some values are empty. In the incomplete case it is implied that there is one and only one solution to every cell in the square. Magic squares that have too few entries and therefore more than one valid solution, or where there is an inconsistent $k$ are invalid.
Example of an incomplete, valid magic square:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
16 & ?  & ? \\ \hline
31 & 20 & ? \\ \hline
?  & ?  & ? \\ \hline
\end{array}
whose solution is:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
16 & 17 & 27 \\ \hline
31 & 20 & 9 \\ \hline
13 & 23 & 24 \\ \hline
\end{array}
If we are given a valid, incomplete magic square where all provided entries are integral (but the constant $k$ is unknown and possibly not integral), does this guarantee all the entries are integral?
I am fairly sure it does, but I cannot write out why. For larger squares with lots of data and many empty cells, I can see it being possible that there are fractions such as $\frac{a}{b}$ and $-\frac{a}{b}$ interspersed throughout the square in such a way that they show up once in every row column and diagonal or maybe even cancel each other out, allowing both rational entries but having an integral $k$.
Furthermore, there is a systematic way of solving magic squares by composing a series of linear simultaneous equations, solving them using gaussian elimination and back substitution- but this method inherently involves division at some point and there is no guarantee that it will not produce fractions. These are just places my mind went when I was thinking about this. How can I proceed?

Well, consider your own example.  Specifically, look at the diagonal $16, 20,24$.  You could divide the entire square by $4$ and reveal the diagonal $4,5,6$.  That can obviously be completed, but the overall square won't be integral.  I think you need more conditions.  Or is it that this square has another completion which is integral?

@lulu If I divided the entire square by $4$, the completed square would have non integral entries, but simply revealing the diagonal is not enough information to complete the square so it is invalid. If i reveal enough information to make the square completable it will include some non integral entries and so not a case we care about.

I don't understand.  My system is perfectly solvable...the given data shows the common sum to be $4+5+6=15$ and you are left with $7$ equations in $6$ variables, so the square has a unique completion (given that it has one, which it clearly does).

@lulu - if a diagonal is known to be $4,5,6$ and any other position is an integer (you need to know one other to get a unique solution) then all the other positions are integers.

@lulu I might be misunderstanding you but if you only revealed the diagonal in the simplified square it would look like this: 4 ? ?, ? 5 ?, ? ? 6 which has at least one other solution 4 6 5, 6 5 4, 5 4 6 alongside the rational solution above. I think there are two solutions because there is not enough information to ensure a unique solution

@Henry.  Yes, that's right.  My error.  Thanks.

@Mukund  Yes, of course you are right.  Error on my part, thanks.

Here is an example of a non-integer unique solution to a question with integers:
Given
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & ? & 2 \\ \hline
? & ? & ? \\ \hline
3 & ? & ? \\ \hline
\end{array}
the diagonals tell you the bottom right square is $4$, and you can find that the central square is $k-5 = 10-k$, so $k=7.5$, giving the unique solution
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 4.5 & 2 \\ \hline
3.5 & 2.5 & 1.5 \\ \hline
3 & 0.5 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{array}
which contains non-integers.
